# java 17, which vendor supported Set to add an element?

Tags: java, set, java-11

I'm trying to migrate my Oracle JDK 11 application to JDK 17.0.7, when I tried to access add() in java.utils.Set, It throws

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I checked with Stackoverflow and found, java.util.Set's implementation is not fully support add() function yet, it was marked as optional.

My question is, Which java vendor's Java 17 it already supported or implemented java Set add() methods?

I have quite a lot Java objects need this function in my application.

If anyone have idea, Please advise.

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking the wrong question, as there is most likely no (or very little) difference between vendors in this case. The real question that you should be following up is *which implementation of `java.util.Set` are you using*? The "classic" `java.util.HashSet` for example clearly supports `add`, but some `Set` implementation returned as a view onto some other data structure might not. What does `yourSet.getClass()` return?

Comment: Yeah, I am using HashSet to create the Set Instance.

Comment: **Show us your code.**  There is no possibility that calling `add` on a HashSet is producing that exception.  However, if your code does `HashSet.of(element)`, that is actually calling `Set.of(element)` which produces an unmodifiable Set.

Comment: @VGR `static` interface methods are not inherited. Therefore, it’s not possible to accidentally invoke `Set.of(…)` via `HashSet.of(…)`.

Comment: @Holger Actually, they are.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: @VGR I did. Not that it was necessary, as [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8:~:text=A%20class%20does%20not%20inherit%20private%20or%20static%20methods%20from%20its%20superinterface%20types.) clearly says: *A class does not inherit private or static methods from its superinterface types*

Comment: @Holger Ah, okay, I didn’t read your statement carefully.  I glossed over the word ‘interface’ and was thinking of static methods in general.  You’re completely correct, static *interface* methods are indeed not inherited.  So my HashSet.of guess cannot be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not depend on the vendor but on the particular class implementing the `Set` interface: some sets are unmodifiable, so you cannot add anything to them.  The Javadoc specifies any usage limitation for each implementing class.  For example a `Set` returned by [`Collections.unmodifiableSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) is, obviously, unmodifiable.

Perhaps during the upgrade of Java you have also upgraded some dependency and the new version of that dependency returns an unmodifiable `Set`.  Check the Javadoc of the method that returns that `Set`.

You'll probably have to modify your code and copy the content of that `Set` in a new modifiable instance, for example:

```java
Set<YourClassGoesHere> newSet = new HashSet<>(oldSet);
```

Comment: Thank you! I did more research and find out, If I create every instance by using
    new HashSet<>();